# How to check if the buffer has filled up completely in Python?

Tags: python, node.js, pipe, buffer

I have a pipe between Node.JS and Python, and I'm sending responses back according to the received requests by Node.JS. But I want to check if the buffer is full or not in Python, and I could not find any documentation somewhere.

I send responses back from Python to Node.JS as follows:
`sys.stdout.buffer.write(binary_response)`

Is there a way to check before writing to the buffer if it is full or not?

Comment: I tried `sys.stdout.buffer.tell()` but the buffer is not seekable. I don't see a way to do this is Python.